# Custom Check Box is not showing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to create a custom checkbox in HTML with CSS. When I am running this code in IE, it’s working properly, but when I try to run it in Google Chrome, it’s showing the default checkbox, not my custom one.

What modification do I need to run it in Chrome?

#### HTML

```
<link href="btn.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
.check {
    width:81px;
    height:78px;
    border: 3px ridge;
    border-color:red;
    border-style:outset;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because IE supports CSS it shouldn't support. Checkboxes can't be edited a lot with CSS, Firefox and Chrome do it right... You could use a background image as a checkbox layout or just make your own with JS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like checkbox styling in WebKit (the rendering engine used by Chrome) is all-or-nothing.

You can turn off all default styles using `-khtml-appearance: none` (you might nowadays require `-webkit-appearance: none` or just `appearance: none`), but I believe that will literally give you no visible checkbox styles, so you’ll have to rebuild the whole thing using the `:checked` pseudo-class and background images.

See:

- http://www.webkit.org/blog/17/the-new-form-controls-checkbox-2/
- http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/using-css-to-style-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-for-safari-and-chrome/